# Select or leave a field blank dependent on a condition without affecting query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to select a field but only under specific circumstance, otherwise i would like it to just be blank or null.  Example

```
Select
a.Name,
c.Hat as FancyHat,
b.Shirt,
b.Shoes,
c.Hat

from
directory a, store b, superHatStore c

where 
a.key = b.key
a.key = c.key
```

now I would only want to display a FancyHat name if it is a 'fancy_hat' example

`where 
c.Type = 'fancy_hat'`

but if I put it in the where clause it is too restrictive... because I also want the name of the hat to be in another field regardless of hat type... maybe I am just doing something wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a presentation-layer issue, not a SQL issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS-Access you can use either the `IIF` statement
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

or the `CASE` statement (if you're using VBA)
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

**EDIT:** So if I'm reading correctly you want (UNTESTED!):

```
Select
a.Name,
iif (c.[type] = "fancy_hat", c.hat, NULL) as FancyHat,
b.Shirt,
b.Shoes,
c.Hat

from
directory a, store b, superHatStore c

where 
a.key = b.key
a.key = c.key
```

Comment: Sorry I am so late to attempt this, I have been getting a "missing right parenthesis error" while attempting this approach.